# rails by default set tmp/ file permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have rails application in docker. Also using gitlab ci for deploy to server. And rails store all cache in tmp folder. When ci starts deploying, they should be delete all cache in tmp file. But in this moment, for tmp file sets sudo permissions and gitlab-runner can't delete cache. By default, tmp file created when application is already started.

Can I indicate in rails configs permission for tmp file, before starting my application.

Or you can advise how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `config.cache_store` in your production.rb file and see where it's set to.

I'd suspect you're running into this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-filestore